# Validation error in api response in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I want to store data through api. It's working but problem is when I add validation it does not give me corresponding message . How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Here is my route

```
Route::post('api/add_user', 'TestApiController@store');
```

Here is my controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validation = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required'
    ]);


    if ($validation->errors()) {
        return $errors->toJson();
    } else {
        $testApi = new testApi();


        $testApi->name = $request->name;
        $testApi->phone = $request->phone;
        $testApi->email = $request->email;

        $testApi->save();


        return "ok";
    }

}
```

Comment: `$errors` is an undefined variable in your code (causing error). use `$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages)` instead. it does all the magic so you don't have to do the checks manually.

Answer (score 2):

to handle that your method should be like this  :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email2' => 'required|email'
        ]);

 if($validator->fails()){
            // here we return all the errors message
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }


        $testApi = new testApi();

        $testApi->name = $request->name;
        $testApi->phone = $request->phone;
        $testApi->email = $request->email;

        $testApi->save();

       // 201 http code means that the server has proceced your request correctly
        return response()->json([], 201);
    }
```

Comment: { 
 "name": "Test2",
    "phone": "01722222222",
    "email2": "test@gmail.com"
   
} here is error in email which email2 . still not giving error response

Comment: if you have a field with email2's name you should put it within the validator if it's required

Comment: if the name is email2 in the request body of your postman, you should put email2 instead of email in the validation

Comment: ok, but if I put any null value , that time also not give any error message in json

Comment: what do you mean by null value?

Comment: { 
 "name": "Test2",
    "phone": "",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
   
}

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually do this. simply

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required'
    ]);

    $testApi = new testApi();

    $testApi->name = $request->name;
    $testApi->phone = $request->phone;
    $testApi->email = $request->email;

    $testApi->save();

    return "ok";
}
```

this will automatically handles validation and returns error message when invalid.

**Update**

if you wanna stick with your approach. this is where you need to change.

```php
if ($validation->fails()) {
    return $validation->errors();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not give any json validation message

Comment: For sure it returns error message. you need to handle it on the client side code.

Comment: I am using postman. { "name": "Test2", "phone": "01722222222", "email2": "test@gmail.com" } here is error in email which email2 . still not giving error response

Comment: 'email2'? there is no validation for 'email2' !

Comment: ok, but if I put any null value , that time also not give any error message in json